# I am unable to set Blazor radio boxes from model

Tags: blazor

I am sure there is something I don't understand about RadioBox in Blazor.

I am trying to set the value of the radio box from the value in a model class.  I have tried a few different attempts at this.  Where am I going wrong?

```
 @page "/RadioBox"
<h3>RadioBox</h3>


<EditForm Model="@Model"> 
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="Model.ButtonValue">
        <div>
            <label>
            <InputRadio  @bind-Value="Model.ButtonValue" /> Option 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
            <InputRadio  @bind-Value="Model.ButtonValue" /> Option 2
            </label>
        </div>
    </InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm> 
<p>Selected Value: @Model.ButtonValue</p>

<button onclick="click">debug</button>
<button onclick="clickSet1">Set 1</button>
<button onclick="clickSet2">Set 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind each option like this:

```cs
   <InputRadio  @bind-Value="Model.ButtonValue" /> Option 1
```

You need to set the Value like this:

```cs
  <InputRadio Value="1" /> Option 1
```

The buttons need to use the component `@onclick` event - not `onclick`.

Here's a refactored version of your page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h3>RadioBox</h3>

<EditForm Model="@Model">
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="Model.ButtonValue">
        <div>
            <label>
                <InputRadio Value="1" /> Option 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <InputRadio Value="2" /> Option 2
            </label>
        </div>
    </InputRadioGroup>
</EditForm>
<div class="m-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => this.SetValue(1)">Set to 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => this.SetValue(2)">Set to 2</button>
</div>
<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <pre>Value :@Model.ButtonValue </pre>
</div>


@code {
    private MyModel Model = new();

    private void SetValue(int value)
        => Model.ButtonValue = value;

    public class MyModel
    {
        public int ButtonValue { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: That helped.  But if I update the model, the radio buttons don't reflect the changes even if StateHasChanged is called.

Comment: As you hadn't shown the code I assumed that were just part of your testing.  See my revised answer.   Note:  you rarely need to call `StateHasChanged` if you logic is correct.  It's built in to the UI handler in `ComponentBase`.

Comment: I was being stupid.  I forgot the @ for the onclick.  It is now working as expected.

Comment: We're all that at times!